# OkHttp(s)URLConnection class is not available in 4.9.0 version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, okhttp

I am having **com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.13.1** jar as dependency in gradle file of my Android project and used as below to get the URLConnection.

```
protected URLConnection getStandardHTTPURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    return new OkHttpURLConnection(url, builder.cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(CookieHandler.getDefault())).build());
}
```

So I updated the jar to 4.9.0 and realized that **OkHttpURLConnection** is not available. It is leading to noClassDefinition exception in the run time.  so what are the alternatives? Is it deprecated or moved under another hood?

Below are my imports.

```
import okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection;
import okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection;
```

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a compatibility implementation you can paste in that's mentioned in the OkHttp 3.14.0 release notes.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3140

Comment: `okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection.d(): [0x95] cannot access instance field q1.b0 p1.l0.n.e.b from object of type Unresolved Reference: p1.l0.n.f (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection' appears in /data/app/...==/base.apk:classes3.dex)`

Comment: We definitely cannot downgrade to 3.13.1 to get the official `internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection` as 3.14.7 is at least needed for compatibility with Android R (as per the Retrofit changelog).

Comment: I posted a workaround here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186560102

Answer (score 0):

From https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/ so I guess they got removed on 4.x

> The Apache HTTP client and HttpURLConnection APIs are deprecated. They
> continue to work as they always have, but we’re moving everything to
> the new OkHttp 3 API. The okhttp-apache and okhttp-urlconnection
> modules should be only be used to accelerate a transition to OkHttp’s
> request/response API. These deprecated modules will be dropped in an
> upcoming OkHttp 3.x release.

Comment: Ok, any thoughts on how to replace it?

Comment: downgrade to the system's built-in HttpURLConnection or upgrade to OkHttp's Request/Response API.

Comment: Or if you want to buy yourself some time, paste the Gist referenced in the changelog above. https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/dd91c0a8854e1559b00f5fc9c7bfae70